# IIS will not bind certificate

Tags: c#, iis, bouncycastle

Using the BouncyCastle API I create certificates and add them to the certificate store, marking the Private Key persisted and exportable.

My key shows up in the local machine's `personal` store and is a selectable option inside IIS manager, however, when I click OK to bind my certificate, I get an error dialog with the following message:-

`A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)`

In Windows Event Viewer, the following is logged:-

`A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the TLS server credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030D. The internal error state is 10001.`

I have verified that my private key is exportable by going to `Action -> All Tasks -> Export...` in Certificates MMC and can see that the radio button to export private key is not grayed out.

Suspecting that it could be a file permissions issue, I also from the MMC went to `All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys` and tried setting `Full Control + Read` on the application pool the site uses in IIS. Same error, in desperation, I have even tried setting it to `Everyone` with no success.

I am unsure what else could be causing this issue, or what other steps I should try.

Here is a [link to a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/563pcH1V) of the code I am using to generate the certificate, in case it provides any useful information.

Comment: Since I couldn't access the pastebin to see your codes, I guess there are something wrong with your created certficate. I guess you want to create a self-signed certficate and bind it with IIS web site, I suggest you could try to follow this [article](http://msftwebcast.com/2019/11/create-and-bind-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-10.html) to do this thing.

Comment: As per my understanding, self-signed certificates created in IIS manager are treated as invalid in Google Chrome even when added to trusted persons because they do not have SAN (Subject alternative name) but only CN.